# Child control event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, events, repeater, datalist, childcontrol

I have structure as below
repeater1->datalist->repeater2

Here child is repeater2, whose parent is datalist and whose parent is repeater1.

How to get repeater2 control event, because of it's child directly I can't get any event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#" class="drop">
                            <%#XPath("@title")%></a>
                            <div class="dropdown_4columns">
                                <div class="col_1">
                                    <asp:DataList ID="dlCategory" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("category") %>'
                                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="menuItems" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <h3>
                                                <%#XPath("@title")%></h3>
                                            <ul class="submenu">
                                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptItem" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("item") %>'>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="hlSubmenuItem" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# XPath("@url") %>'
                                                                ToolTip='<%# string.Format("{0}", XPath("@title")) %>'><%#XPath("@title")%></asp:LinkButton> </li>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>
                                            </ul>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Here I want linkbutton click event
I can't find anyway to do this

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: code updated, plz check...!?!

Comment: What do you mean by _get repeater2 control event_? Do you want to run some code when a button is clicked in repeater2?

Comment: Yes Shai Cohen, you got me right, same I update in my question...!?!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure of what you want to achieve, I guess `RaiseBubbleEvent` should be of some help :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.raisebubbleevent.aspx